# Convert a string of numbers into numbers for matching in R

Tags: r, string, loops, math, sequence

I have a problem where I would like to see if a string is a sequence increasing by 1. That is, the difference between any 2 consecutive numbers is 1. The string is in collapsed form:

```
91011
89909192
18192123
```

where the first two are strings increasing by 1 but the third is not. This is since 91010 is 9,10,11 and 89909192 is 89,90,91,92. Yet 18192123 is 18,19,21,23 so difference is larger than 1.

How can I check whether each of these strings in the examples above (and in general) are increasing by 1 or not using R?

Of course lets assume that the maximum string length will be 32 and hence...

```
99999999999999989999999999999999
```

is the longest string for which the consecutive numbers increase by 1 as we have 99999999999999998 then 9999999999999999 which is 2x16 digits long.

So worst case scenario we need to get 16 loops I think but I'm not sure if there is a simpler way then appending a sequence and pasting for each of the 16 loops.

Comment: How do you know when to break a string into constituent numbers? AKA, how are you parsing the strings?

Comment: Input is a text file, if that's what you are asking. Have a list of these strings and they are imported as characters.

Comment: No. I meant how do you know to break 999999 into 9, 99, 999 and not 9, 9, 9, 9, 9. Both are equally valid parses and neither passes your requirement.

Comment: What I have tried is taking the first digit and adding 1 then appending that, then looping until the new string has the same length as the original string. e.g I take 9, then add 1 to 10. Then put 10 after 9. Then so on until I have the same length which is 91011. Also for example if I did this with the 3rd example, I would get 18 then 1819 then 181920 then 18192021 and the string lengths match but they are not the same so t works, but have to try changed the first digit(s) until it takes u half the string length and do the process again.

Comment: Question: Why does `91010` become `9,10,11` and not `91,01,0`?

Comment: Oh so I would try the first digit and do the process, and check they match. Then try the first 2 digits and so on until I get to floor(n/2) digits.

Comment: 91010 is just the string. I want to CHECK if it is increasing. So 91010 s not increasing so I would output "No". :)

Comment: @TonyHellmuth That doesn't answer my question, and I'm afraid without providing us logic for how to parse your number strings, there is no exact answer here.

Comment: As a counter example to your argument, 99100 will fail but it is valid. 9 + 1 is 10 not 91. But 99 + 1 is 100 which is how this string was created. You need to fix your parsing logic first before even attempting any R code, or any language for that matter.

Comment: That's my problem! I'm not sure how to choose the parsing. Because sometimes the number starts as K digits long. Then becomes k+1 digits by the end! That is my actual problem.

Comment: Now we are getting somewhere. :)

Comment: Because i don't know how to parse it, I just brute forced all version. So lets go with 91010 example. I would try 9 then make is 910 then 91011. Since 91011 is not 91010 I would try the next length of first 2 digits by parsing 91 then 92 then 9 and stop there since we have the length desired and we end up with 91929 which is not 91011. Since we cannot go any further (as it is impossible for there to be any more consecutive numbers) we stop and say these are not consecutive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with a recursive function: you get the first digit, try to add the next ones until you reach the desired length and if it does not work, try again, taking the first 2 digits and so on:

```
cons_d <- function(str, nb=1) {
    l_str <- nchar(str)
    if(nb>=l_str) return("No") # if the number of digits you're trying is more than the length of strings then return "No"
    n1 <- as.numeric(substr(str, 1, nb))
    i <- 1
    while(nchar(n2 <- paste(n1:(n1+i), collapse=""))<l_str) {i <- i+1}
    if(n2==str) return("yes") else cons_d(str, nb+1) # if you get the right string, return yes, else, try again with one more digit
}
```

Testing on your test strings:

```
cons_d("91011")
[1] "yes"
cons_d("89909192")
[1] "yes"
cons_d("18192123")
[1] "No"
```

Comment: Yep! Exactly what I need thank you! I was doing this but with so many more lines of code. Love the substr instead of the extended loop.